# Calling BackgroundWorker synchronously

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I want to call the background worker synchronously. I want execution of the code to end when backgroundworker has completed its execution.
My code for BackgroundWorker is here :

```
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
    ...
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    //wait for execution to end 
}
```

One way of doing it will be to check the status again n again until its execution is completed but is there any other good way of doing it ?

Comment: What's the point of using a BackgroundWorker if you synchronously wait for it?

Comment: Why not just move the part of the code you want to execute after the BackgroundWorker is complete under RunWorkerCompleted event ?

Comment: the code I want to execute gives error when executed in the same thread so i need that code to be run through background worker.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: You should concentrate on fixing that error, not on building work arounds.

Comment: @KooKiz - for starters, an async background worker won't block the UI. Also, the OP may want to perform some other steps in-between but decided not to show those steps in the example.

Comment: @ChrisGessler But if you synchronously wait for the backgroundworker to end, you'll block the UI anyway

Comment: Which version of C# are you using?  4? 4.5? 5?

Comment: @KooKiz - not necessarily.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: @ChrisGessler "Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await", how is that synchronous? ;)

Comment: @ChrisGessler: await isn't doing a synchronous wait. It just looks like synchronous code...

Comment: @ChrisGessler: There is no C# 4.5. There is C# 4, C#5 and .NET 4 and .NET 4.5. Don't confuse those.

Comment: I am using this code in wcf service so UI wont be issue here and m using .NET 3.5

Comment: @ChrisGessler: You implicated it, by saying that synchronously waiting for a background worker to end doesn't necessarily block the UI and linking to the introduction to `await` and `async`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - the OP (and others) used the word "synchronous" not me.  I'm merely trying to guess at what the OP really needs /  wants despite the word chosen.  The original question makes no mention of a UI, Windows Service, etc so it's difficult to know what problem I'm really trying to solve, as with many of these SO questions so sometimes it's necessary to read between the lines.  If async/sync wait doesn't really matter, the problem may be solved in several different ways, whereas a sync wait limits the possibilities.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Actually, there was a "C# 4.5" for a very brief moment in time, at least that's what everyone was calling it before Microsoft's official announcement.  But you're right, it was actually C# 4 + .NET 4.5.  I think people called it that because it was easier to say than "C# 4 using the .NET 4.5 compliler".  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=797

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't want your code to execute asynchronously, don't put it in a `BackgroundWorker`...

```
{ 
    DoWork();
}
```

However, if there is some obscure reason why you absolutely need to have the code in the `BackgroundWorker`, you can use the following:

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker(); 
worker.DoWork += DoWork; 
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => 
                             {
                                 RunWorkerCompleted(s, e); 
                                 mre.Set();
                             };
// ... 
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
mre.WaitOne();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Objective:** BackgroundWorker should execute in sync.

Created an windows application form. On click of button1 it should execute BackgroundWorker synchronously
and returns engage the UI, So user not able to do anything till completion of BackgroundWorker task.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 

    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    BGimplent obj = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
         obj = new BGimplent();
        obj.eveBG += obj_eveBG;
        i = 5;
        obj.MyProperty = 5;
        obj.DoConfig();
        obj.ManualReset.WaitOne();

        obj.MyProperty = 10;
        obj.MyProperty = 11;
        obj.MyProperty = 12;
        obj.MyProperty = 13;

        obj.MyProperty = 14;
    }

    void obj_eveBG(string s)
    {
        obj.ManualReset.Set();
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}



/*
*******************************************************
    Paste below code in adding new class i.e. Class1


*/
public delegate void delBG(string s);

class BGimplent
{
    public event  delBG eveBG;


    private ManualResetEvent mnuReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public ManualResetEvent ManualReset { get; set; }

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public void DoConfig()
    {
        ManualReset = mnuReset;

        bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
        bgWorker.ProgressChanged += bgWorker_ProgressChanged;
        bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();            
    }

    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {   
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (eveBG != null)
            eveBG("Value of MyProperty: " + MyProperty.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: @GhostCat yes, you are right. I tried my best to answer the question through my post.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for your advice, I edited code and tried to present it more attractive.

Comment: I would further "shorten" the empty method bodies - but much better now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code that would be after `//wait for execution to end` should be placed in the `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` method.