# Sync two BackgroundWorkers

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker, thread-sleep

I'm writing a C# wrapper, to a hardware controller using its [Modbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) protocol.
The controller has 12 inputs and 12 outputs.

The wrapper has two tasks:
1. Polling the controller's inputs at a constant interval (i.e. 50ms).
2. Running preconfigured sequences, which changes the controller's outputs.

The sequence is XML based:

```
<opcode>
  <register>0</register>
  <bit>1</bit>
  <duration>500</duration>
</opcode>
<opcode>
  <register>0</register>
  <bit>0</bit>
  <duration>0</duration>
</opcode>
....
```

In the above sample, the controller should turn output #0 On and after 500ms turns it Off.
The pauses between operations was achieved using `Thread.Sleep()`.
In the past I've used just one BackgroundWorker. When not running the sequence it did the polling.

**The challenge:**
The new demand for the wrapper is that it could detect changes in the controller's inputs while running a sequence.
I've modified the wrapper to have 2 backgroundworkers, one for polling and the other for setting the output registers.
Each of the BackgroundWorkers calls a seperate function on the controller, they do not try to access each other data nor they share any data.

**Current code:**

```
private void workerSequence_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (!terminating)
        if (e.Argument != null)
            DoSequence(e);
}

private void workerPoll_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (!terminating)
    {
        DoPoll();
        Thread.Sleep(pollInterval);
    }
}

private void DoSequence(DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string sequenceName = e.Argument.ToString();

    foreach (configurationSequencesSequenceOpcode opcode in sequencesList[sequenceName])
    {
        if (workerSequence.CancellationPending)
            break;

        byte register = opcode.register;
        bool bit = opcode.bit;
        int duration = opcode.duration;

        SetRegister(register, bit, false);
        Thread.Sleep(duration);
    }

    e.Result = e.Argument;
}
```

**The problem:**
It's seems like the two BackgroundWorkers interfere with each other. I've tried using `Semaphore`, `Monitor.Wait()` and `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()` but the BackgroundWorker, which deals with the sequences, doesn't handles them well. The main issue - its sleep duration is not consistent as before.

Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: I would try to solve this in one thread with a state machine. E.g. create a big loop, which runs forever and inside do, what you need to do currently based on the state. Send a sequence, check output etc.

Comment: How do they "interfere with each other", and why do you need synchronization?

Comment: When using just one thread, I'm unable to poll the inputs register, as the `Thread.Sleep()` function locks it. I've added some code above.

Comment: The backgroundworker uses a synchronization context to run the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted on the original thread. That might cause an automatic synchronization between the backgroundworkers. Just write the same code using two threads.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213650/calling-backgroundworker-synchronously

Comment: Did you ever got it working well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Thread.Sleep` outside of test code is generally not ideal.

You can use `System.Threading.Timer` objects for both these requirements.

---

**EDIT** if you want to prevent concurrent calls, you can use a lock to implement mutual exclusion.

Create an object to lock on that can be seen by both timer handlers:

```
public object gate = new object();
```

---

For the polling, you want to set up a timer like this:

```
var pollTimer = new Timer( HandlePoll, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite );
...

void HandlePoll( object state )
{
  lock ( gate )
  {
    DoPoll();
  }
  pollTimer.Change( pollInterval, Timeout.Infinite );
}
```

I've set the period to `Timeout.Infinte` so the timer doesn't repeat. This means `pollInterval` is the time between one poll finishing and another starting - which will be different to the poll period if `DoPoll()` takes some time.

Doing it this way also prevents the timer ticking again while a previous poll is still running.

---

You can use the same principal to send the commands, but you will have to manage the current index into the `sequencesList`:

```
var seqTimer = new Timer( HandleSequence, null, 0, Timeout.Infinate );
int seqIndex = 0;
...

void HandleSequence( object state )
{
  var opcode = sequencesList[sequenceName][ seqIndex ];

  byte register = opcode.register;
  bool bit = opcode.bit;
  int duration = opcode.duration;

  lock( gate )
  {
    SetRegister(register, bit, false);
  }

  seqIndex++;
  if ( seqIndex < sequencesList[sequenceName].Count )
  {
    seqTimer.Change( duration, Timeout.Infinte );
  }
}
```

Or something along those lines ( but with suitable error handling! )

You can handle termination and cancellation by just disposing the timers.

---

BTW, there is an excellent ( and free ) ebook about threading that you could read:

[`Albahari: Threading in C#`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: Thanks for your code. Tried your method, but still I'm facing problems with synchronization.
Seems like in case I'm sending one message to the controller while still haven't got an answer for a previous message, its crushes. The exception is: `The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.`

Comment: @toy4fun I've added mutual exclusion to my answer.

Comment: It's working perfectly now. I've tried the same `Lock()` mechanism with the 2 BackgroundWorkers solution and it also works. I just need to decide which solution is considered as best practice - BackgroundWorkers vs. Timers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How about queueing up the sequence names to one thread that waits on a BlockingCollection?

Pseudo, one thread per device channel:

```
while(true)
{
    if outputQueue.TryTake(thisSeqName,50)
    {
        foreach (configurationSequencesSequenceOpcode opcode in sequencesList[thisSeqName])
        {
            outputOpcode(opcode);
            DoPoll();
        }
    }
    else
        DoPoll();
}
```

Hmm.. this won't work correctly as it will probably poll too often when a sequence is being sent.  Needs rethink, but I'm still of the thought that one thread per device is going to be a better approach.

```
int startTick=Environment.TickCount;
while(true){
    int now=Environment.TickCount;
    waitInterval=50-(now-startTick);
    if outputQueue.TryTake(thisSeqName,waitInterval)
    {
        foreach (configurationSequencesSequenceOpcode opcode in sequencesList[thisSeqName])
        {
            outputOpcode(opcode);
            int now=Environment.TickCount;
            waitInterval=50-(now-startTick);
            if (waitInterval<=0)
            {
                DoPoll();
                startTick=Environment.TickCount;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DoPoll();
        startTick=Environment.TickCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This is similar to my first solution which used one BackgroundWorker. The problem here is that I don't know how much time consuming the DoPoll function is, yet I need to keep the duration between changing the output register precise. This is why I've chosen the 2 BackgroundWorker architecture.

Comment: WTF?  I tried to update my code but the code block did not work correctly and I posted a pile of gunge!

Comment: Use 4 + 4 spaces for each tab level :)